# Bootstrap Carousel navigation disappears when adding images

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When having one image in the carousel the navigation at the bottom shows:

[image]

But when adding a second image to the code the navigation disappears and the second image is added to the bottom of the first:

[image]

This is my current code with the second image added:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="img/colette.png" alt="Beach" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <!-- When adding this, nav hides and new img is shown on bottom-->
        <div class="item">
            <img src="img/apple.png" alt="apple" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove `active` class from 2nd image parent. It must be used only once in all slides within a carousel.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman removed, but problem still persists.

Comment: Please create a fiddle of your code.

Comment: Check if your CSS is overwriting any of the classes?

Comment: @DeepakBandi I have been searching extensively. Would this have to be the issue? I don't see how my code is incorrect in any way.

Comment: Yes, I kinda had a same issue, the wrapper div had 'display:table', once it was changed to 'display: block' it worked.

Comment: @DeepakBandi Ok I will just have to look further into it, thank you. Going to leave this up just for the sly chance someone has encountered the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check working demo on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r2wLz6xr/190/)

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/450x350" alt="Slide 1">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        Caption Slide 1
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/450x350" alt="Slide 2">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        Caption Slide 2
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/450x350" alt="Slide 3">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        Caption Slide 3
      </div>
    </div>        
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Your Carousel works great, just not on mine. I guess I have some type of overriding css causing a issue. Will look further into it until I find it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    </ol>

<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="img/main.jpg" alt="Image">
            <div class="carousel-caption">

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="img/main2.jpg" alt="Image">
            <div class="carousel-caption">

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try it now, maybe it will be good (just use your source of images)